# Best Way to Wrap Retrofit Calls for Main Thread

Tags: java, android, observable, retrofit

I am trying to improve some Java Android code another developer wrote.

This API call made multiple times in the app

```
@GET("/api/v1/smb/machines/{machineName}")
Call<TLPJsonData<MachineData>> getMachineInfo(@Path("machineName") String machineName);
```

Each time there is some variation of this code

```
SMBAPI.get().getMachineInfo(DeviceManager.getMachineName()).enqueue()
```

(I have removed the `onResponse()` / `onFailure()` code so this post is not super long.)

I would like to know the best way to hopefully create a class that makes the API call with the error handling, etc. and then allows the results of the call to be returned to the main thread so I can move what is essentially boilerplate code that is copied four different times in the app into a single class.

I'm guessing RxJava and/or Observables are the way to go here but I'd like some insight / guidance on how to implement that before I go down a rabbit hole.

Comment: `I'm guessing RxJava` do you currently have rxjava in your project ?

Comment: I do not have RxJava in use currently. I have not used it before so I was planning to write a test project for trying to implement it but that's why I am looking for feedback on the best approach before I start writing test code.

Comment: yeah - reason for asking is simply because you might be opening your team up to more/new problems you don't know how to deal with. introducing Rxjava just for the sake of getting rid of some minor duplication might not be worth the pain you could potentially have of debugging new bugs :)

Comment: that being said, I would suggest you try Rxjava out on the side, create a new project or try it out on a unit test or something. nothing prevents you from creating your own observable and learning how to get values from it on different threads, when you then come back to doing it with an api call, you'll find all the same functionality is also there.

Comment: There are several API calls that are duplicated throughout the app and so I am hoping to consolidate all the calls to any given API endpoint so that it will be easier to implement better error handling / user feedback as well as making any changes if the API calls are updated in the future. I will look into RxJava and also CompletableFuture that was mentioned below and see if either allows me to accomplish what I'm hoping to do.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Java but do not want to use RxJava so you can use `CompletableFuture`. Change your Api Service to this:

```java
@GET("/api/v1/smb/machines/{machineName}")
CompletableFuture<TLPJsonData<MachineData>> getMachineInfo(@Path("machineName") String machineName);
```

now you can easily work with `CompletableFuture` like this:

```java
final CompletableFuture<AccessToken> machineInfo = SMBAPI.get(). getMachineInfo(DeviceManager.getMachineName());
```

then you are able to use a lot of functions of `Future` like this:

```java
machineInfo.handle((result, throwable) -> {
      // work with result or throwable, you can use exceptionally function as well
    }
```

Search about `CompletableFuture` to find useful functions for your case.